# If $f,g : (a,b) → \mathbb{R}$ are diﬀerentiables and for all $x \in (a,b)$, $f(x)g'(x) \neq f'(x)g(x)$, in between two zeros of $f$ is a zero of $g$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $f,g : (a,b) → \mathbb{R}$ are diﬀerentiables and for all $x \in (a,b)$, $f(x)g'(x) \neq f'(x)g(x)$, in between two zeros of $f$ is a zero of $g$.

I am trying to prove this but am quite stuck.

Does this proposition hold at the first place? If it does, how can we prove this?
(We call $x$ a zero of $f$ if $f(x)=0$).

Comment: What's the proposition?

Comment: Essentially, if you have $p,q$ to be the roots of $f$. Then, you would have to show $g(p)>0,g(q)<0$, or $g(p)<0,g(q)>0$

Comment: For some reason I'm not clear on, it's better to also include the question in the question (as opposed just in the title).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $u,v\in(a,b)$ be zeroes of $f$ and assume that $g$ has no zeroes in $(u,v)$.
From $f(u)=f(v)=0$ and the given inequality, we obtain that $g(u)$, $g(v)$ are  non-zero, hence also positive.
This allows us to consider $h(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ on $[u,v]$.
We have $h(u)=h(v)=0$. By Rolle $h'(x)=0$ for some $x\in(u,v)$. But $h'(x)=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2}\ne0$ for all $x\in (u,v)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $W = f' g - g' f$. Then $W \neq 0$ by the condition, and if $x_1,x_2$ are successive zeros of $f$, then 
$$ W(x_1) = f'(x_1) g(x_1), \qquad W(x_2) = f'(x_2) g(x_2), $$
and these both have the same sign. But $f'(x_1)f'(x_2)<0$ because otherwise the mean value theorem and the intermediate value theorem would imply that $f$ has another zero between $x_1$ and $x_2$. Hence we also have $g(x_1)g(x_2)<0$, so the intermediate value theorem implies that $g$ has a zero between $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm_separation_theorem , an application of this result to solutions of differential equations.